# How to get the <input>'s value?

Tags: javascript, html

#### How do I get the `<input>`'s Value

1. I'm trying to make a page viewer through the iframe, so. I have searched up some things to help. But nothing has correctly done something to help. I've tried

#### Codes I used that didn't work.

Found on W3Docs, I used this portion of a code...

```js
function getInputValue() {
  // Selecting the input element and get its value 
  let inputVal = document.getElementsByClassName("inputClass")[0].value;
  // Displaying the value
  alert(inputVal);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Type " id="inputId" class="inputClass">
<button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">Get Value</button>
```

It didn't properly alert the value of the input.

I also tried this, its supposed to have a variable inside of a function that I can simply put inside a button's `onclick`

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input_id").value;
```

this also failed in return. nothing happened when I put it inside of a button.

#### Additional

Is there any source I can find things like this?

Comment: What do you mean by "make a browser through the iframe"? If you're trying to access an input in a different frame/iframe, you won't be able to

Comment: I didn't mean a "browser through iframe". I meant something where you can view pages throught the input. like https://wear-a-mask.ml or something. @Codebling

Comment: `var input = document.getElementById("inputId").value;` (not input_id)

Comment: @Kinglish input_id was the Id of the input.

Comment: @Theodore, you can find the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript

Comment: Yes, but in your code above the ID of the input is shown as `inputId` which would make `document.getElementById("input_id").value;` not do anything

Comment: I pasted the code you claimed doesn't work into a snippet and it appears to work just fine. You're also causing some confusion because you claim `getElementById("input_id")` doesn't work but in your example the ID is `inputId`

Comment: @j08691 I fixed it. SO, i'm trying to close the question.

Comment: @Theodore You fixed what?

Comment: @j08691 the code i claimed didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to get the value of an input is by making a form:

```js
    <form class="my-form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type " name="my-input">
        <button>Get Value</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        let form = document.querySelector(".my-form");

        form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault() // This prevents the window from reloading
        
        let formdata = new FormData(this);
        let input = formdata.get("my-input");

        alert(input);
        });
    </script>
```

That's the best way of geting data from inputs. You simply put the values of the form with **new FormData()**, and then you get the input values with **formdata.get("input_name")**

Answer (score 1):

Like @Kinglish said, you made a typo when using getElementById.

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Type " id="inputId" class="inputClass">
<button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">Get Value</button>
<script>
  function getInputValue() {
    let inputVal = document.getElementById("inputId").value;
    alert(inputVal);
  }
</script>
```

It should be "inputId", not "input_id".

Answer (score 0):

I dont get why there is a '[0]' in between the objects..maybe this can help you. Declare the variable first and then use it.

```
<input id="numb">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

function myFunction() {
  var x;
  x = document.getElementById("numb").value;
}
```

Comment: _"I dont get why there is a '[0]'"_ What do you believe that `getElementsByClassName` returns?

Comment: Oh ok, i just researched it, it gives you an "undefined" if there a no classes available. I learned something aswell ;)